# What tiresome procedure can I follow to find the exact value of inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry

Because of convenient trigonometric identities, we can find the exact value of things like $\tan70^{\circ}$ because $70^{\circ}=2\cdot35^{\circ}$ (tangent double-angle identity), $35^{\circ}=36^{\circ}-1^{\circ}$ (tangent angle difference identity), $3^{\circ}=3\cdot1^{\circ}$ (tangent triple-angle identity) and $3^{\circ}=18^{\circ}-15^{\circ}$ (tangent angle difference identity), $18^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot36^{\circ}$ (tangent half-angle identity), and $15^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot30^{\circ}$, leaving $\tan70^{\circ}$ in terms of the more well-known $\tan30^{\circ}$ and $\tan36^{\circ}$. I am fairly sure that we can find exact values by following similar procedures for all $\tan\theta$ ($\theta$ in degrees) as long as $\theta\in\mathbb{Q}$.

So, can we do the same for finding the exact values of inverse trigonometric functions? Specifically, I am looking for a method of finding the exact value of $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$ in terms of things like integers, radicals, and complex numbers (which are required in the case of $\tan70^{\circ}$, for example), but not other trigonometric functions or infinite series. I am not asking for the exact value itself as I am sure no one would like to burden themselves finding it, but rather just the method so that I may.

Comment: What is the exact value of $\tan 1{^\circ}?$  Since this angle is not constructible, I would be surprised to learn that its tangent can be computed exactly.

Comment: *I am fairly sure that we can find exact values by following similar procedures for all $\tan\theta$ ($\theta$ in degrees) as long as $\theta\in\mathbb Q$.*  I rather doubt this, although I suppose it depends somewhat on what you mean by "exact values" and "things like...".   For example could you find an exact expression for $\tan20^\circ$?

Comment: @saulspatz I think you and I are thinking along the same lines.

Comment: @mweiss Exactly so.

Comment: @saulspatz $60^\circ = 3 × 20^\circ$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan So you're saying that you can get a cubic for $\tan 20^{\circ}$ from the triple angle formula?  That sounds right.  I think $3^{\circ}$ is constructible, if I remember right, so the same argument would apply to $\tan 1^{\circ}$.  I'm still surprised to learn it, and I think the OP should have included this in the question.

Comment: [Not sure if it helps but] you could read up on Taylor series if they are not already a familiar topic. For example, you could check WolframAlpha to see the series expansion for $\arctan(x)$ [**here**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+for+arctan(x)). Even still, plugging in e.g. $x=1$ yields an infinite series [the sum of odd reciprocals, alternating b/w positive and negative] yet I doubt that encountering this series "out in the wild" would lead one to believe that it converges to the very specific, exact value of $\pi/4$.

Comment: @saulspatz I believe that all nonconstructible angles that are still rational numbers have exact values that are complex numbers, because their nonconstructibility comes from having to solve the cubic equation in the triple-angle identity.

Comment: @mweiss By exact expression I mean an expression that does not use any further trigonometric functions or infinite sums, but rather just integers, radicals, and complex numbers. Complex numbers are required in all exact values of nonconstructible angles. In the case of $20^{\circ}$, we must solve the triple-angle identity with $60^{\circ}$, whose solution is complex. This also tells us that $20^{\circ}$ is nonconstructible with a compass and straightedge.

Comment: @DavisRash If you mean all *integral* multiples of $1^{\circ}$ I agree with you, as I said in response to MohammadZuhairKhan's comment.  I doubt it's true for *rational* multiples.  How would you calculate $\tan \frac15^{\circ}?$  You'd have to solve a quintic.

Comment: @DavisRash Where does the $150$th root come from?  I'm not very interested in the answer, just the method.  It would be a lot easier if you add this to your question, rather than trying to put it in a comment.

Comment: @saulspatz $\tan\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\sqrt[150]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}-\sqrt[150]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}}{\sqrt[150]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}+\sqrt[150]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}}$.

Comment: @saulspatz $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$ so we let $\theta=\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}$ and $n=150$. Then we try again with $\theta=-\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}$ and subtract the two equations to eliminate $\cos\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}$ or add them to eliminate $\sin\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}$. If we do both then we can divide them to get tangent.

Comment: @saulspatz Choosing $n=150$ has the answer in terms of $\cos30^{\circ}$ and $\sin30^{\circ}$. We can choose any $n$ that gives us values of $\cos n\theta$ and $\sin n\theta$ that we know, all for different looking answers with really high-order radicals.

Comment: @DavisRash Excellent, but there is a problem in that there are $150$ different $150$th roots of a complex number, and since you have $4$ such roots in your formula, there are $150^4$ possible interpretations of it.  While you have shown that $\tan \frac15^{\circ}$ is expressible in terms of radicals, we can't really say that this formula gives the value, but only that the value is one of the values of the (multi-valued) formula.  A similar problem arises with Cardano's formula for the cubic, where the cube roots have to be chosen carefully.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, but those are all principal roots. I asked and later answered a very related question after I posted this one here, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2817353. While there are 150 different solutions to the equation $y^{150}=x$, only one of them is $y=\sqrt[150]{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Just an illustration (I cannot post this as comment):

$$t_3=\tan3^\circ=\frac{-2 \sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)}+\sqrt{6 \sqrt{5}+15}+1}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}+5}-2 \sqrt{4 \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)}-\sqrt{66 \sqrt{5}+150}+12}}$$

$$t_1=\tan1^\circ=-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{t_3^3+\sqrt{-\left(t_3^2+1\right)^2}+t_3}+\frac{i \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) \left(t_3^2+1\right)}{2 \sqrt[3]{t_3^3+\sqrt{-\left(t_3^2+1\right)^2}+t_3}}+t_3 $$

So, yes, you can calculate $\tan N^\circ$ for any natural number N exactly.

Comment: $tan 1^o  ≈ sin 1^o ≈  \frac{1}{2\pi} Rad.$. You probably could find $\pi$ in terms of some certain mathematical constants or relations containing integers.

Comment: And you may do the half-angle identity with $\tan1^{\circ}$ to get $\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}$ or the triple-angle identity again for $\frac{1}{3}^{\circ}$. This and the fact that we can get exact values for all natural numbers leads me to believe we can for all rational numbers too.

Comment: @DavisRash: Yes, you can get halves of degree because you can solve quadratic equations and thirds because you can solve qubic equations. But how would you calculate $\tan\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}$ or $\tan\frac{1}{7}^{\circ}$?

Comment: @Oldboy You got me there. It looks like we can do $\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}+\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}+\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}+\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}+\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}=1^{\circ}$, but this requires solving a quintic equation.

Comment: @Oldboy Well, it turns out we can use De Moivre's theorem to get $\sin\frac{1}{5}^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2i}\sqrt[150]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}-\frac{1}{2i}\sqrt[150]{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}$, as well as other forms depending on what angle you want. Like in that instance I tried to make the angles $30^{\circ}$, but we can do $45^{\circ}$, say. I'm not sure how useful these expressions are given that they are in super high-order radicals, but I believe this shows it works for all rational angles now.

Comment: @DavisRash Please explain this calculation of $\sin \frac15^{\circ}$