# Comparing the trigonometric functions of any two angles in the same quarter of the unit circle

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving, number-comparison

I'd like to talk about the comparison of the trigonometric functions of angles.

For example, both angles in degrees, different from one another, are known and guaranteed to be in the same quarter of the unit circle. The question is how to compare their trigonometric functions without using tables or calculators.

How does one need to think when comparing two angles?

For example, we have two angles, one is 11 degrees, and another one is 13 degrees.

Comparing sines is easy since we know that for angles from 0 to 90 degrees, the greater the angle the greater the sine value, so $$\sin11^{\circ}<\sin13^{\circ}$$We also know that for angles from 0 to 90 degrees, the greater the angle the less the cosine value, so $$\cos11^{\circ}>\cos13^{\circ}$$Similar thing goes for tangents and cotangents: $$\tan11^{\circ}<\tan13^{\circ}\\\cot11^{\circ}>\cot13^{\circ}$$

How to compare their sines/cosines with their tangents/cotangents without using tables or calculators?
Thank you!

Comment: I picture the graphs of sine etc. in my mind.

Comment: We are talking about mathematical proof on why are they less or greater than one another. Any person competent at math can imagine these graphs, but 'this is greater/less than this because the graph says so' seems... pretty unconvincing for those reviewing the answers to the problems of that type.

Comment: You should be able to compare sine and tangent functions by knowing the zeros and sign of the cosine function. Comparing sine vs cosine is simply understanding a $45+\epsilon$ degree right triangle. Cosine vs tangent seems harder...

Comment: @DavidDiaz Regarding sine-tangent comparison, I do understand the zeros and sign of the cosine function. Cosine has zeros in pi/2 and 3pi/2 angles at any amount of 2pi additions. I still don't understand what to do when it comes to my case, two angles in the same quarter of the unit circle, like 11 and 13 degrees. Their cosines are both positive and their tangents are less than 1.

Comment: $1 > \cos 11^\circ >0$, therefore, $\sin 11^\circ < \frac{\sin 11^\circ}{\cos 11^\circ} = \tan 11^\circ$.

Similarly, $1 > \cos 13^\circ >0$.

Finally, since the sine function increases on $(0,90^\circ)$ while the cosine function decreases, the tangent function increases on  this interval.

$\frac{x}{y} < \frac{x+a}{y-b}$ for $y>b$ and positive $x,y,a, b$.

Comment: @DavidDiaz This compares sine and tangent of the same angles. What is greater if we take, for example, sine of 13 degrees and tangent of 11 degrees?

Comment: The short answer is to just use a calculator. The long answer is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2816624/431789 . Check out the comments for an exact sine function.